# Debugging python in vscode - namespace package not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a project

```
project
-- src
---- namespacepackage
------ subpackage
-------- this.py
-- folder
---- execute.py
```

And in `execute.py` we have

```
from namespacepackage.subpackage.this import something
```

The autocomplete workes nicely having set up `.env` and `settings.json`. But I don't get how I should setup `launch.json` to make the terminal work. I keep receiving import errors (No module named namespacepackage.subpackage).

Note that a namespacepackage doesn't have a `__init__.py` because the package is combined from several repositories.

Current launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `.env` file that VScode will pick-up on. In this, you have to extend the python path:

```
PYTHONPATH=src
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that when importing other files, VSCode starts to search from the parent folder of the currently opened file by default, so it cannot find `src` or `namespacepackage` from the folder.

Solution: We can add the following code at the beginning of the file, which adds the path of the file that needs to be imported to the system path to help VSCode find the file:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

or

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append('./')
```

[image]

In addition, when encountering the "Pylint ([import-error](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#undefined-variable))" error but the code can be executed, we can use

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--disable=E0602"
    ],
```

in the settings (`settings.json`) to close it. (It is recommended that you turn off Pylint errors or warnings after the code is modified to be executable.)